# Check if outlook is synchronizing changes to exchange server redemption

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I sometimes get a MAPI_E_EXTENDED_ERROR while trying to process folders and items.

```
Error: Outlook is synchronizing local changes made to items in this folder. 
You cannot   remove this folder until the synchronization is complete.
```

Is there a way I can check if outlook is synchronizing changes or prevent that from happening?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not exposed by the MSEMS MAPI provider...